# Responsive jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want for specific width, specific click animations but it's not working. Why?

Here an example:

From 0 - 959px > anim1 From 960 - 1279px > anim2 From 1280 - 1699 > anim3 From 1700 - open end > anim4

Here is my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() > 959) {
    $("#mains").click(function(){
    anim1();
    });
}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() > 1279) {
    $("#mains").click(function(){
    anim2();
    });
}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() > 1699) {
    $("#mains").click(function(){
    anim3();
    });
}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() < 1700) {
    $("#mains").click(function(){
    anim4();
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Note: that for width>1700 all the animation functions will be called

Comment: I fixed your code a bit.. You do not need that many .ready(). Also some debugging. http://jsfiddle.net/B2FU9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read through your existing code and think about what it will do if the window width happens to be 1750:

- Your first if test with `> 959` will be true so it will bind a click handler that does `anim1()`.
- The second if test with `> 1279` will *also* be true so it will bind another click handler that does `anim2()`.
- The `> 1699` test would *also* be true, binding a third click handler that does `anim3()`.
- The fourth if test would be false since it has `<` rather than `>`, but in fact for a width of 1750 you want `anim4()` to run.

So then a click would call the first three animations.

What you *need* is an `if/else if/else if/else` structure so that only one of the four `animX()` functions is used. Also you probably want to do the test inside the click handler so that it uses the window width at the time of the click, not the width at the time the page loads. So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mains").click(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w < 960)
      anim1();
    else if (w < 1280)
      anim2();
    else if (w < 1700)
      anim3();
    else
      anim4();
  });
});
```

Note that at the beginning of the click handler I've put the `$(window).width()` into the (imaginatively named) `w` variable to save having to repeat those two function calls in the `else if` statements.

Comment: Nice! This is the best Answer! it's working so good! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You are binding the animation on `$(document).ready()` based on the screen size. For example when the DOM is ready and the window width is less than 1700 only the function with anim4() will be used. What you need to do is place the window width check inside a single binding.
For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mains").click(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 959) {
            // do something
        } else if  ($(window).width() < 1700) {
            // do something else, etc.
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have mistaken the conditionals. Also you can use just one document ready event handler and use an if else if statement to distinguish between cases. The statements should specifically set the width borders. Something like:

```
if ($(window).width() < 969 ) {
  anim1();
} else if ($(window).width() >= 970 && $(window).width() < 1200) {
  anim2();
}
```

The widths are as everyone can see examplary.

Except that there could be errors in anim* functions, but those errors would definitely mess up the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding events on the basis of width size. I would recommend to check width in event handler and perform action accordingly

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mains").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 959) {
            anim1();
        }
        if ($(window).width() > 1279) {
            anim2();
        }
        if ($(window).width() > 1699) {
            anim3();
        }
        if ($(window).width() < 1700) {
            anim4();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that the first two `else if` cases will never be called here, because the widths they apply to would trigger the first `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          if ($(window).width() > 1699) {
                 anim3();
           }else if($(window).width() > 1279){
                 anim2();
            }else if($(window).width() > 959){
                  anim1();
           } 
   });
```